# How to get italic style using docx4j in java?

Tags: java, docx4j

I want to get applied italic styles on word file data using docx4j api. but i am not getting it, anyone can help me please.

rPr.getI() and rPr.getICs() not working for it...

Below is my Input docx file text....

**REFERENCES**
Curry, R. A., & Tempkin, B. B. (2010). *Sonography: Introduction to normal structure and functional anatomy* (3rd ed.). St. Louis: Saunders.
Frank, E., & Long, B. (2011). *Merrill’s atlas of positioning and radiographic procedures* (12th ed.). St. Louis: Mosby.

In this file i have **Maintitle** character style that contains italic styles, italic not applied directly....

```
try {
        File docxFile = new File("/Users/gwmc-062/Desktop/temp/test.docx");
        WordprocessingMLPackage wProcessorPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(docxFile);
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wProcessorPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        Document wmlDocumentEl = (Document) documentPart.getJaxbElement();
        Body body = wmlDocumentEl.getBody();

        List<Object> paraList = TraversalUtil.getChildrenImpl(body);
        for (Object paraObj : paraList) {
            String paraStyle = null;
            boolean paraStyleFlag = false;
            if (paraObj.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.docx4j.wml.P")) {
                String paraText = XmlUtils.unwrap(paraObj).toString();
                PPr pPr = ((P) XmlUtils.unwrap(paraObj)).getPPr();
                if (pPr != null && pPr.getPStyle() != null) {
                    paraStyle = pPr.getPStyle().getVal();
                    paraStyleFlag = true;
                }
                List<Object> paraWRList = TraversalUtil.getChildrenImpl(paraObj);
                for (Object paraWR : paraWRList) {
                    String charStyle = "";
                    boolean charStyleFlag = false, isItalic = false, isBold = false;
                    if (paraWR.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.docx4j.wml.R")) {
                        RPr rPr = ((R) XmlUtils.unwrap(paraWR)).getRPr();
                        if (rPr != null && rPr.getRStyle() != null) {
                            charStyle = rPr.getRStyle().getVal();

                            if (charStyle.toLowerCase().contains("italic"))
                                isItalic = true;
                        }
                        if(rPr != null && (rPr.getI() != null || rPr.getICs() != null)){
                            isItalic = true;
                        }
                        if(rPr != null && (rPr.getB() != null || rPr.getBCs() != null)){
                            isBold = true;
                        }
                        List<Object> textList = TraversalUtil.getChildrenImpl(paraWR);
                        for (Object tObj : textList) {
                            Object textObject = XmlUtils.unwrap(tObj);
                            String className = textObject.getClass().getName();
                            if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("org.docx4j.wml.Text")) {
                                String textContent = ((Text) textObject).getValue();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }//END paraWR LOOP...
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Might be set in the styles, rather than as ad hoc formatting.  Unzip the docx and inspect the XML.  Or use the Docx4j Helper AddIn for Word to look at it.  Then, if you are still having problems, please post your code and the XML.

Comment: Hi Jason you may have a look on it now ....

Comment: You say you have a Maintitle character style that contains italic styles, but you code doesn't check for that character style?

Comment: Yes....... for your knowledge, if i unzip this docx file, Background XML structure for this docx file doesn't have any property regarding italic style.  -- Thanks a lot to give time for this problem...

Comment: you need to post the actual XML for one of the paragraphs, please

Comment: Hi Jason. XML for any one paragraph is too long that can not be post.. Is there any option to attach the file...

Comment: Just post the XML for the bit which says " (2011). Merrill’s atlas "

Comment: Hi Jason... Thanks a lot to give your precious time for this problem, but my problem has been solved out.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The actual solution is:-

Style tStyle = (Style)rPr.getParent();
if( tStyle.getRPr().getI().isVal()){
   isItalic = true;
}
```